Не могу забрать данные из HTML страницы, ибо у меня - InLineKeyboardMarkup, а нужно Reply... Не понимаю как поменять эти клавиатуры в моем коде
Аналогично декорация @dp.message(text=["web_app_data"]) - не работает.
async def command_start_handler(message: Message) -> None:
    await message.reply(
        "Нажмите на кнопку ниже, чтобы просмотреть весь наш ассортимент техники в продаже.",
        reply_markup=webapp_builder()
    )


@dp.message(text=["web_app_data"])
async def webapp_data(message: Message) -> None:
    await message.answer(message.web_app_data.data)```

